# How to extract the audio of a WebM file using pure C

Tags: c, webm, opus

I have a simple C program all it does is it opens a webm file and it reads the top elements of it without any external libraries. Let's say I have a function that finds each SimpleBlock on the file. How can I get the audio out of it?

```
typedef struct simple_vint
{
    uint8_t width;
    uint8_t data[8];
} simple_vint;

unsigned char bits = buffer[0];

simple_vint id;
        id.width = 1;
        mask = 0x80;

        while (!(buffer[0] & mask))
        {
            mask >>= 1;
            id.width++;
        }

        id.data[0] = buffer[0];

        if ((len = read(fd, buffer, id.width - 1)) != id.width - 1)
        {
            printf("Uh oh, read id data error!\n");
            break;
        }

        // Get EBML Element ID.
        for (int i = 1; i < id.width; ++i)
        {
            id.data[i] = buffer[i - 1];
            bits = buffer[i - 1];
            printBinaryInt(bits); // This just prints each bit of a byte
        }

        // Get EBML Element Size first byte.
        if ((len = read(fd, buffer, 1)) != 1)
        {
            printf("Uh oh, read first size byte error!\n");
            break;
        }

        simple_vint size;
        size.width = 1;
        mask = 0x80;

        // Get EBML Element Size vint width.
        while (!(buffer[0] & mask))
        {
            mask >>= 1;
            size.width++;
        }

        buffer[0] ^= mask;
        size.data[0] = buffer[0];

        // Get EBML Element Size vint data.
        if ((len = read(fd, buffer, size.width - 1)) != size.width - 1)
        {
            printf("Uh oh, read id data error!\n");
            break;
        }

        // Get EBML Element Size.
        for (int i = 1; i < size.width; ++i)
        {
            size.data[i] = buffer[i - 1];
            bits = buffer[i - 1];
            printf(" ");
            printBinaryInt(bits);
        }

        uint64_t data_len = vint_get_uint(&size);
        printf("Element Size: %lu\n", data_len);

        if ((len = read(fd, buffer, data_len) != data_len))
        {
            printf("Uh oh... Could not read all the data. Read %u instead of %lu", len, data_len);
        }

        printf("DATA:\n");

        for (size_t i = 0; i < data_len; i++)
        {
            printBinaryInt(buffer[i]);
        }
```

I tried to create a simple program that reads the info of the elements and then read the element it self with the data. The thing is I cannot understand how are the SimpleBlocks structured so I can get the opus audio data out of them.

Comment: I expect that using the opus library would work best.  Apparently WEBM also supports vorbis, so you may need to check for that and use the vorbis libraries also.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel can be educational, but some things are just better done by using a library to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @BradLanam I know and I have downloaded the libopus and let's say im sure the files use opus. How to use that library with the webm file? Don't I have to extract the audio and then give it to the opus codec?

Comment: @Shawn I know it is better to use a library and believe me if I could, I'd do it. But I cannot find a static library for doing that in C. I am also a little scared with external libraries because I'll want to compile that to wasm using emscripten and I'm not sure yet how well it's gonna go.

Comment: I cannot understand the structure of the simpleBlocks either, the docs (Matroska.org) say that he simpleBlock is like the Block but without all the extra information  but it still has some information so which of them are that "extra" ones?

Comment: Not hard once you understand the EBML structure.  You need to know what track id belongs to the audio track. That info is in Segment > Tracks > TrackEntry > TrackNumber. Then remove all the other TrackEntries and the Segment > Cluster > SimpleBlock elements that belong based on the Track Id in the SimpleBlocks. The track id is the first byte in the SimpleBlock binary element. I know you are using C but my project may be able to point you in the right direction. Also, the project has a simple EBML viewer (screenshot at the repo.) [SpawnDev.EBML](https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.EBML)

Comment: Great references: [EBML specification](https://github.com/ietf-wg-cellar/ebml-specification/blob/master/specification.markdown) [Matroska Spec](https://www.matroska.org/technical/elements.html)

Comment: This reference is even better, it shows the layout of the SimpleBlock header. [Draft Spec](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-lhomme-cellar-matroska-04.txt) And I was wrong, the SimpleBlock Track Id is an EBML VINT, not a single byte (per spec.)

Comment: @LoneSpawn Can the webm audio be split in more than one cluster? Like, will I have to take the file cluster by cluster and take the simpleBlocks? or one cluster has usually the audio's frames?

Comment: Each cluster is a chunk of time with a mix of both audio and video SimpleBlocks mostly interleaved (Ex. audio SimpleBlock, video SimpleBlock, audio SimpleBlock, video SimpleBlock, video SimpleBlock, audio SimpleBlock, etc...) progressing up through the clusters duration, from start to end. You would need to go through each cluster and remove the tracks (based on TrackId) you do not want and remove the necessary TrackEntry elements from Segment > Tracks. And finally update the modified cluster's size, and then the parent segment's size. SpawnDev.EBML shows a binary view of element bytes now.

Comment: Alright I understand. Once I do that, what I need to do is extract each audio frame from the simpleBlock elements. For simplicity let's say each simpleBlock contains 1 audio frame only. Any suggestion on doing that? @LoneSpawn  and thank you for the help so far.